# AIME 1984 Problem 12

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

A function $f$ is defined for all real numbers and satisfies $f(2+x)=f(2-x)$ and $f(7+x)=f(7-x)$ for all $x$. If $x=0$ is a root for $f(x)=0$, what is the least number of roots $f(x)=0$ must have in the interval $-1000\leq x \leq 1000$?

Comment: https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=1984_AIME_Problems/Problem_12

This gives a solution.  I'd suggest reading through it and asking further questions if anything doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why anything congruent to 4 (mod 10) is also a root.

Comment: Because $$f(10+x)=f(7+(x+3))\\=f(7-(x+3))=f(4-x)\\=f(2-(x-2))=f(2+(x-2))=f(x)$$ and $f(4)=f(2+2)=f(2-2)=0$.